# Starting SimpleProxy as a service

Tags: services

I am in need of running a simpleproxy as a way to connect from VPN to a firewall internally for configuration purposes.  I can run the command below and it works correctly.

```bsh
simpleproxy -L 9009 -R 192.168.100.1:909
```

However I need to run this on reboot of the device and I am struggling with setting it up as a service.  I have created the file /etc/systemd/system/simpleproxyasdm.service with the configuration below.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/simpleproxy -d -L 9009 -R 192.168.100.1:909
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
Description=Simple Proxy ASDM
After=network.target
```

When I launch the service nothing happens from my perspective.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I obviously can launch it manually when I reboot but I would love to have it just work.

Comment: what is the output `systemctl status simpleproxyasdm`?

Comment: what is the output of  `journalctl -u simpleproxyasdm`

Comment: journalctl shows the following: `Jul 06 13:16:15 lo-console systemd[1]: Started Simple Proxy ASDM.
Jul 06 13:16:16 lo-console systemd[1]: simpleproxyasdm.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 06 13:16:16 lo-console systemd[1]: simpleproxyasdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.`

Comment: systemctl shows `â— simpleproxyasdm.service - Simple Proxy ASDM
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/simpleproxyasdm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Mon 2020-07-06 13:16:17 UTC; 4min 30s ago
  Process: 22316 ExecStart=/usr/bin/simpleproxy -d -L 9009 -R 192.168.100.1:909 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22316 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to take out the `-d` option, as systemd will daemonize it for you.

Comment: Hey Qaxi! Please make sure that your answer is detailed (use the edit feature).